get all telegram bot users
How can I get all the users who used my bot if the database of these users was permanently deleted from my hosting provider? Is it possible?
the points:

There is a bot that had users
My hosting provider deleted the database of these users after 7 days of non-payment
You have to get it somehow

I don't know how to do this

That's not possible without your own dataset.
Telegram does not keep track of all users that ever talked to your bot, or If they do, it's not possible to retrieve that information from Telegram.
